# How to build ttfautohint on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ubuntu

I am trying to install a recent version of ttfautohint. Ubuntu has one [ttfautohint 0.97 package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/ttfautohint) which is pretty old and [does not work properly with grunt-webfont and Ubuntu 14.04](https://github.com/sapegin/grunt-webfont/issues/162).

My question is, how can I build a more recent version of tthautohint on Ubuntu 14.04 so that I can use it in combination with grunt-webfont?

So far I tried this, with little success, it keeps failing on dependencies.

```
# dependencies from INTSTALL.git
sudo apt-get install autoconf -y
sudo apt-get install automake -y
sudo apt-get install bison -y
sudo apt-get install flex -y
sudo apt-get install git -y
sudo apt-get install libtool -y
sudo apt-get install perl -y

# additional dependencies after ./configure stopped with errors a couple of times
sudo apt-get install g++ -y
sudo apt-get install pkg-config -y

./bootstrap
./configure  #on my box ./configure still fails
```

`./configure` fails with the following error:

```
checking whether wcswidth is declared without a macro... yes
checking for stdint.h... (cached) yes
checking for HARFBUZZ... no
configure: error: Package requirements (harfbuzz >= 0.9.19) were not met:

No package 'harfbuzz' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables HARFBUZZ_CFLAGS
and HARFBUZZ_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

Comment: What error messages did you get when you say your compilation "keeps failing on dependencies"?

Comment: Most important of all: Have you read the file `INSTALL.git`?  It lists all prerequisites.

Comment: I did read the INSTALL.git, but I might not have understood the whole thing fully. I installed some ohter dependencies, those were missing in the original question, see update.

Comment: After running `./bootstrap` it said that I'm ready to run `./configure`, which I did, that fails with error `configure: error: Package requirements (harfbuzz >= 0.9.19) were not met: No package 'harfbuzz' found`. Maybe I should continue reading the "compilation with mxe (on Unix, for Windows)" section and execute all of that? All I need in the end is a command line only tool for Ubuntu so that grunt-webfont can run properly, if running the "compilation with mxe (on Unix, for Windows)" section nessesary for that purpose?

Comment: `INSTALL.git` lists the *additional* requirements.  If you then call `./configure`, you see the normal dependencies, as is common with most Unix libraries or programs.  One of those dependencies is HarfBuzz, indeed :-)

Simply continue installing packages as requested by the `configure` script (e.g. `harfbuzz`, `harfbuzz-devel`) until it succeeds.

Comment: I think there is no harfbuzz package for Ubuntu, I compiled it myself, but it is still an issue; `checking whether host operating system is Darwin... no qmake: could not exec '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qmake': No such file or directory configure: error: Calling /usr/bin/qmake -project failed.` I will keep trying ;)

Comment: Doing a quick google search for 'Ubuntu', 'RPM', and 'harfbuzz', I get https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/harfbuzz as a first hit...  I'm not an Ubuntu user, but this looks promising :-)